# Semgrep not finding two lines of code with a 'patterns' section

Tags: c#, semgrep

I have a Semgrep rule:

```
rules:
  - id: create-chat-client
    patterns:
      - pattern: var $X = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(...); 
      - pattern: var $Y = new ChatService.ChatServiceClient($X);
    languages: 
      - csharp
    message: <pass>
    severity: INFO
```

And I am trying to match this code:

```
using Grpc.Net.Client;
using GrpcChat.ProtoBuf;

var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:8888");
var client = new ChatService.ChatServiceClient(channel);
```

These match separately, but the 'patterns' should be a "AND" match and it fails. I must be missing something obvious. Anyone see anything?

Answer (score 4):

Using `pattern-inside` works:

```
rules:
  - id: chat
    patterns:
      - pattern-inside: |
          var $X = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(...); 
          ...
      - pattern: var $Y = new ChatService.ChatServiceClient($X);
    languages: 
      - csharp
    message: <pass>
    severity: INFO
```

with this test case:

```
using Grpc.Net.Client;
using GrpcChat.ProtoBuf;

var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:8888");
// ruleid: chat
var client = new ChatService.ChatServiceClient(channel);
```

when I run a test:

```
% semgrep --test rules/
✓ All tests passed!
```

Comment: Why use `pattern-inside` here? In the [docs](https://semgrep.dev/docs/writing-rules/rule-syntax/#patterns-operator-evaluation-strategy) under "patterns operator evaluation strategy" it says that patterns are "intersected", and that I understand as an "AND".